# Laser diode driven by a voltage source seems OK

Tags: arduino, diodes, laser

I have bought a [KY-008](https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-008_Laser_sensor_module) laser diode module and connected it directly to an Arduino's output pin. It has been blinking (on for 0.5 second, off for 0.5 second) for an hour. I am very puzzled.

From [various](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10082/why-is-a-laser-supply-so-tricky) [sources](http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laserdps.htm#dpsmld) [I have](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEupSfzEIXM) [read](https://www.thorlabs.com/NewGroupPage9_PF.cfm?ObjectGroup_ID=1832), all seem to say that a laser diode is supposed to be driven by a constant current source, and that it is a very delicate device, vulnerable to the tiniest of over-voltage.

I cannot find KY-008's schematics, so cannot be sure what is on the board. From the cheapness of it (¥2 RMB, or $0.3 USD), I assume it does *not* have a proper constant current source.

So, why does the laser diode seem OK (so far) driven by a voltage source (Arduino output pin)? Is the normal lifetime of a laser diode so long that even a shortened one can last for hours? Is "catastrophic optical damage" less catastrophic than it sounds? Is there something nifty on KY-008? Am I missing something?

Comment: Because it's possible to fake one under fixed circumstances, just as with a normal LED.

Comment: Fake what? A constant current source?

Comment: Linked datasheet says "Power consumption : 30mA at 5V". And you can see a resistor on the board, which will do a good enough job as a "current source" as long as you don't exceed 5V.

Comment: A ¥2 laser diode can be mistreated, especially if you don't want or need full output power. I bet if you have a ¥28,000 [UV laser](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=L375P70MLD) you will take rather more care with the driver.

Comment: Who knows?   It could be anything from current limit in the module **to the limited drive capability of an ATmega pin**.  Or it could fail 5 minutes from now.  Seeing what you can get away with for a while can indeed have its place *but it is not engineering*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks. This is for a DIY project, and nothing in that project calls for a "high-end" solution. Given how cheap it is and how long I seem to be able to get away for, it simply does not make sense to spend an order of magnitude (or two) more to get a proper driver. Engineering has a technical dimension, it also has an economical dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact module and it does not have any complicated circuitry, just 2 resistors and a laser diode. Something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the V+ looks pretty pointless. Maybe it serves some point (like turning on the laser diode faster) but if you're just going to play with it, you don't need to connect it.

The arduino has a linear regulator, so the 5V would be pretty constant.

One of the resistors is in the circuit board of the KY-008 and one is soldered onto the laser itself. The one on the diode is the resistor in series with the diode. That resistor provides the current limiting.

With a resistor of a constant value and a power supply of a constant voltage, it ought to supply a stable current to the diode.

Thus, if the manufacturer set the resistance so that the ideal current is within the safe zone of the laser's capability, it wont blow up.

Thus it is current limited. Just make sure the voltage supply doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks @Bradman175. That makes things clear. And you are right that V+ needs *not* be connected. Connecting SIG and GND works pretty fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like that module may have more to it than meets the eye.

The resistor appears to be related to a control input and it's too high value (10K) to be a simple series resistor. Maybe there is a chip or a two-transistor current source on that PCB mounted at right angles to the main PCB - the laser diode itself would be mounted on the *edge* of the thin PCB an there is a second PCB beside it.

You can rip it apart and find out. A microscope might help.

[image]

Comment: A good analysis - that 10K resistor likely buffers the "signal" input. The actual laser is well-buried and potted. If it has 3-wire connections, an internal photodetector monitors optical power for feedback control. If the laser has 2-wire connections, current control is external, usually in the form of a current-limiting series resistor of small value (approx 100 ohms in this case). I'd guess this one is a 3-wire active-control type

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The truth is that middle pin (+5V) needs *not* be connected for it work (although you may still connect it). So, I think @Bradman175 's answer is more accurate. But yours is still a good analysis. Thank you.

Comment: @NickLee - yes, Bradman175 takes the cake. Your Arduino output is working very hard to supply all the laser current. I'll suggest you're not getting 5v into the laser. These simple laser modules can be switched fast. You can PWM them nicely for variable output - have fun!

Comment: While we are at it, I may as well ask one more question. @glen_geek, how fast do you expect it can be switched?

Comment: @NickLee - Speed is not limited by the laser, but by parasitic inductance & capacitance inside the module combined with the current-limiting series resistor. A hand-waving guess would be switching time in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expand on bradmann's answer.
This is a very bad way to drive a laser, but because of some of the things they did, it's slightly *less* bad.

The schematic is like so, as posted by bradmann:
[image]

As pointed out, V+ does look pointless at first glance. However, I think that it was assumed that `Sig` was an input pin, when in reality it's an analog output. This pin is used to check the health of the diode. As the voltage between `sig` and `gnd` lowers, so does the health of the diode. The manufacturer expects you to regulate the voltage of `vcc` on your own, which is not a desirable thing in a breakout.

Judging by the breakout, I'd say you're safe to use up to 12 volts on `vcc`, and no more. Using 5 volts will extend the life of the diode, however.

However, 635 nm diodes are strange in the fact that they are indeed voltage driven. This is because (low powered) 635nm diodes are the only commercially available that have a *positive* resistivity. This fact, along with the low price of the components themselves makes them the obvious choice in most low grade laser applications.

The expected lifetime of these diodes are usually in the ballpark of 10,000 hours. Many times out of ten, they last much longer if properly used.

**Catastrophic damage** is simply thermal runaway (which doesn't occur much in these diodes...), which will burn the laser to the point of no functioning.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you said. You are saying, I can switch the laser on and off by setting the voltage on V+, and use the SIG pin to monitor the resistance of the diode? By the way, that's a great expansion. Thank you.

Comment: @NickLee yes, the lower the voltage on `SIG`, the less healthy your diode is.

Comment: The most enlightening part of your expansion is that exceptional *positive resistivity* of it. Indeed, when I searched for more cheap laser diodes on the web, the green ones always come with a more complicated circuit and with higher prices. It seems only the red ones can be so cheap and simple. Then, I searched for a more technical description on this positive resistivity of red laser diodes, but I came up empty. Can you point me to a source which describes this exceptional quality?

Comment: @NickLee If you're looking for a why, I cannot give you that. I'm just a hobbyist. And I have nothing that could really explain that. However, if you're looking for evidence for my claim, check out some datasheets: http://www.oe-company.com/products/opnext/visible/UOSE_DS_HL6354MG_55MG_Rev0.pdf **(page 3 graph 2)**

Answer (score 0):

It probably contains a current limiting resistor, much like what you would use for an LED.  The resistor approximates a current source and allows the laser to operate without burning itself out.  Of course, the downside is that the brightness of the laser is now dependent on the supply voltage, but in something like a laser pointer it really doesn't make that much difference.  It also means the laser most likely isn't being run at full power, just to make sure that supply voltage variations don't damage it.

Comment: as it heats up as well, there will be a pretty large difference in output. There is no optical feedback to ensure constant optical output power. What the OP needs out of the laser probably doesn't involve constant optical output power, or even just constant power in general. It's hard to tell because they didn't mention the use of it

Comment: Yeah, that's also true.

Answer (score 0):

On the linked picture, I can see a resistor R1 next to the connector - that must be the current limiting resistor that allows it to be operated directly from 5 volts.